# How do you save a function's data to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Let's say I want to take function `test_function` and write it's data to a csv file that can be read by python later.  How can I do that?

Just a sample function:

```
def test_function():
    games_won = 4
    games_lost = 5
    average_time_sec = 6.0
    some_list = [1,2,3,4]
    some_tuple = (1,2,3,4)
```

EDIT:
This is what I tried:

```
def test_function():
    games_won = 4
    games_lost = 5
    average_time_sec = 6.0
    some_list = [1,2,3,4]
    some_tuple = (1,2,3,4)

def main():
    output.write(test_function)

main()
```

Comment: What have you tried already?  File IO is pretty straight forward, why not attempt it yourself first?

Comment: I'll post an update of my primitive attempt.  It isn't much, but it's as far as I managed to get on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
import csv
import os.path

resultFile = open("path to your destination file" , 'wb')

wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')

some_list = [1,2,3,4]

wr.writerow(some_list)
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this method to output the entire function at once?